# function in a Matrix manipulation

Tags: ruby, matrix, lambda

I'm trying to set an function as a matrix element and then I want this function to be called when matrix-multiplication is done..
Pseudo Example :

```
f = lambda {|x| Math.log(x) }
m1 = Matrix[ [f,0], [0,f] ] #scale matrix
v1 = Vector[10,10]
```

Now when I do  :

```
v1.covector * m1
```

I want to get the logarithmic scaling factor..
How do I force the vector coord instead of being multiplied by the scaling factor to become argument to a call to f()
I want to be able to add different scaling functions later.

EDIT:

As I mentioned when I multiply matrices I want it to go like a normal multiplication but whenever a matrix element is a function, then use the other element as a argument instead of multiplying.
It will probably work for me even if there is requirement that only f.e. the right element can be a function, I would probably be able to rearrange the matrices around.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special about `Matrix` here, your question is equivalent to:

*How can I get `42 * f` (and presumable `f * 42`) to return `Math.log(42)`.*

I wouldn't recommend it, but you could do it with a custom class using `coerce` as follows:

```
class LogInsteadOfMultiply
  def *(other)
    Math.log(other)
  end

  def coerce(other)
    [other, self]
  end
end

f = LogInsteadOfMultiply.new
f * 10 # => Math.log(10)
10 * f # => Math.log(10)
```

The example you gave should work as you want it to.

Comment: what if I want to preserve the multiplication behavior and have this coerce-behavior only if the f parameter is a function.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Maybe update your question with other examples?